# Cypress: how to split numbers found in divs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, cypress

I have a test that is going into an elements `span > div` but there are two of them so when I run the test it concatenates both of them into one number `13,900879,210`. I need it to give me them separately to compare them such as `13,900` and `879,210`. Here is my code. Can anyone help with this?

```js
cy.get(`div[id=2]`).find('span').find('div').invoke('text').then((nums) => {
  cy.log(nums) // 13,900879,210
})
```

**Edit - example HTML that can cause this issue**

```
<div id="2">
  <span>
    <div>13,900</div>
  </span>
</div>
<div id="2">
  <span>
    <div>879,210</div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML code will help give a better understanding of your situation.

Comment: Please add the HTML to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really split the combined text (unless you know how many characters in each).

You can get the texts individually,

```js
cy.get(`div[id="2"]`).find('span').find('div')
  .then($divs => {
    const nums = [...$divs].map(div => div.innerText)
    cy.log(nums) // ['13,900', '879,210']
  })
```

where

- `$divs` is a jQuery object holding both divs
- `[...$divs]` converts the jQuery object to an array of (raw) elements
- `.map(div => +div.innerText)` maps elements into their text values

To work with integers, add a `+` to the map

```js
cy.get(`div[id="2"]`).find('span').find('div')
  .then($divs => [...$divs].map(div => +div.innerText))
  .should('deep.eq', [13900, 879210])
```

Answer (score 0):

[You can use Cypress' `.each()` function](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each#DOM-Elements) to iterate through each element yielded.

```js
cy.get(`div[id]=2`).find('span').find('div').each(($el) => {
  // $el is a JQuery element, so we can use JQuery functions like `.text()`
  cy.log($el.text());
});
```